# How to use href to create links for dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am beginner programmer and I making a website in html,css, and javascript. I am tryng to make a dynamic list that upon click will take me to another html file. I am having trouble with the execution though as I am trying to use .href. Below is a snippet example of my code and I was wondering if anyone has any advice on what I can do.

```
<body>

<ul> </ul>
    
</body>
<script> 

const people = [
    {name: 'john doe', link: 'johndoe.html'},
    {name: 'John Appleseed', link:'johnappleseed.html'}
]

var item = document.createElement('a');
var item.href = 'people.link'




</script>
```

Comment: From your code, people is array of object. [..] is array and {..} is object.. So you should use "people[index].link" instead "people.link"

Comment: in this case of code what would index mean. Sorry, I am a bit confused.

Comment: Index is index of array starting from 0.. In your code, you have 2 array so you have array 0 and array 1.. people[0] have object name "john doe" and link "johndoe.html" and people [1] have name "John Appleseed" and link "johnappleseed.html". Example, when you call people[0].link the result it "johndoe.html"

Answer (score 0):

You Need to loop over people array and create `li` and `a` element and append it to the `ul` element in DOM

```js
const people = [{
    name: 'john doe',
    link: 'johndoe.html'
  },
  {
    name: 'John Appleseed',
    link: 'johnappleseed.html'
  }
]

people.forEach((item) => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = item.link;
  link.innerHTML = item.name;
  li.appendChild(link);
  document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yep, now my code is working without needing a specific index. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user16285000 please accept and upvote my answer if i solve your problem. Thank you